# How to solve linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: objective-c, swift, compiler-errors, linker-errors, exit-code

i am getting this error when i am performing archive for my app. 
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
can any one help me to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many different problems for the same error message.

**1)** if you had two same `constants` in different classes then also this issue happens.

**2)** if you have accidently imported a `.m file` instead of `.h file` in an implementation file.

**3)** This error can also be occurred if you have imported `two different versions` of `same library` ,in this case just remove the older version and keep only one version.

**4)** Adding the `"other linker flags"` in `"Project"` and not in `"Targets"`. So, you move it to `"Targets"`, it shouldn't be in `"Project"`.

**5)** Check it out in **project->target->build settings-> search enable bitcode->set NO** in DEBUG

check out this .. if it's OK then once do like following.

**Menu > Product > Clean** ... then Run the project

Hope it helps you..  :)

Comment: glad..:).. if this is helpful then you can UpVote my answer... and if your issue is solved then you can accept my answer...@HarrySaggu.:)

Comment: ld: warning: object file (/Users/atpl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MySpot-cgdnssssdyrnsuafgomstwexqdhu/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MySpot/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libPods.a(Pods-dummy.o)) was built for newer iOS version (9.1) than being linked (8.0)
ld: could not extract files from bitcode bundle for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Are you sure you've selected Enable Bitcode to NO.  You can check it out in project->target->build settings-> search enable bitcode->set NO in DEBUG (good to remember to try to update libs before test release, maybe it'll contain bitcode already). Then Edit Scheme -> Run -> check if you have DEBUG config atm.

Comment: yes , i got solution. thanks i have set bitcode -> no and changed the deployment target form 8.0 to 9.1. that's it.

Comment: glad, I could help..:)