# Google maps SDK is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

I am trying to use google maps SDK in my project. I just used my existing framework (drag and drop). But when I am running project, I got this error:

> **ld:** `/Work/myProject/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps(GTMStringEncoding.o)` does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting `ENABLE_BITCODE`), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
>
> **clang:** error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use `-v` to see invocation)

I have checked bit code in build settings and it was in YES. I can't find solution for this.

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088618/impact-of-xcode-build-options-enable-bitcode-yes-no

Comment: How you installed sdk manually or using cocopods

Comment: I installed manually

Comment: see this     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873206/how-to-solve-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation/37873354#37873354

Comment: Maybe your library was compiled without `bitcode`, but the `bitcode` option is enabled in your project settings. Try to set it to `NO` to Enable `Bitcode` in your target Build Settings and the Library Build Settings to remove the warnings. From this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html), it states that bitcode is the default, but optional for iOS Apps. If you provide bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle need to include bitcode.